# Which free merge utility is used by Drupalians?

Tags: drupal

I've tried Araxis merge and it's good to use. However it is too costly.

I need only file and folder diff. I also need merge for two files.

Although this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) lists all of the free tools but it is really difficult to conclude which tool will be best.

**I'm curious which is the most recommeded free merge tool for Drupalians!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure Drupalian have specific needs merging-wise compared to other web makers :D

Try **Kdiff3** ( http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/ )which is dead simple.

Sorry I talked about **opendiff** which I use on my mac but it doesn't seem to be available for windows. But if you are on mac it is part of the original install.

Comment: But while comparing how can I edit files on the right and left panes in kdiff?

Comment: I take it you mean : "How do I choose left or right pane chunk", at the top of the UI you have buttons labeled A B and C. You simply select the chunk in the window editor and then click on the button A if you want this window chunk or B. You also have a little multiple arrow goind down wich jumps to the next chunck automatically everytime you click on the A,B or C button.

Comment: And just to make sure : I don't know of a  merge utility that would allow direct text edition in one of the pane. You merge first, then when you are done, you use your favorite text editor to edit some more.

Answer (score 0):

Command-line diff (together with colordiff), vimdiff, emacs has quite good implementation as well...

Comment: Although you are right to mention them, I didn't because I never could wrap my head around those. I think it is good to mention that they are on the rather steep-learning curve end.